# @BeforeScenario issues in JGiven Stage (with Spring Support)

Tags: spring, jgiven

Enjoying using JGiven with it's Spring support!

However, I'm having issues with `@Autowired` playing nice with `@BeforeScenario` in a `Stage` class (annoted with `@JGivenStage`.  I have a minimal spring configuration *(which reads a couple of property files, scans for components etc)* and is denoted with `@EnableJGiven` i.e.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJGiven
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
    value = { "classpath:/config/qa.properties", "classpath:/config/env-${spring.profiles.active:}.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mytest.qa.api", "com.mytest.stage", "com.mytest.qa.ui" })
public class SpringTestConfiguration {}
```

I'm tyring to create a JGiven scenario which has several methods but only does setup **once** (as it takes several minutes) inside the `Given` stage. The feature e.g. `MyFeatureTest` *(names changed for brevity)* is as follows: -

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringTestConfiguration.class)
public MyFeatureTest extends SpringScenarioTest<MyGiven, MyWhen, MyThen> {

    @Test
    public void analysis_should_be_correct() {
        given().I_am_at_the_home_page_with_example_dataset_analysed();
        when().I_click_on_analysis();
        then().I_expect_the_analysis_should_be_correct();
    }

    @Test
    public void download_should_be_correct() {
        given().I_am_at_the_home_page_with_example_dataset_analysed();
        when().I_click_on_download();
        then().I_expect_the_download_should_be_correct();
    }

}
```

My `MyGiven` class is as follows: -

```
@JGivenStage
public MyGiven extends Stage<MyGiven> {

    @Autowired
    private QaApi qaApi;    // QA API use to hit API directly e.g. for setup

    @Autowired
    private HomePage homePage;

    public MyGiven I_am_at_the_home_page_with_example_dataset_analysed() {
        homePage.visit().login(defaultUsername, defaultPassword);
        return self();
    }

    @BeforeScenario
    private void setupSingleAnalysedUpload() {
        qaApi.uploadAndAnalyseExampleDataSet();              // !!!! qaApi is NULL !!!!
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is that when I run a scenario (or several tests of a scenario) that the setup `setupSingleAnalysedUpload()` method is only called once (as it's very slow).

My approach was to annotate this method with the `@BeforeScenario` annotation.  However, the `protected QaApi qaApi;` is null *(doesn't get initialised via the `@Autowired` annotation)*.

> **Note** - If I comment out the `setupSingleAnalysedUpload` method and stick a breakpoint on `homePage.visit().login` line then `QaApi` is initialised without issue - assuming spring life-cycling issues with `@BeforeScenario` annotation.

Completely stomped - my gut feeling is that there is missing functionality in the jgiven-spring library?   If so, what is the best-practice work around?

Comment: Which JGiven version are you using? There were major changes in version 0.14.0 regarding the Spring integration.

Comment: I'm using `0.12.1` - will upgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: That worked! Feel free to add as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Great! I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in [v0.14.0](https://github.com/TNG/JGiven/releases/tag/v0.14.0)

Comment: Thanks Jan - great job on this library - it works really well and I love the extra life cycle annotations - means each layer (1) scenario (2) stage (3) page objects / api are all super clean (especially with Spring + autowiring) as you can see from the example above.